# can't get stdout to a variable

Tags: shell

it seems silly... I don't know what I am doing wrong....

I need to change the .txt files encoding to utf-8.
here the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for NOME_ARQ in *.txt do

##1 - verify file encoding and store in CODIFICACAO
CODIFICACAO=$(file --mime-encoding "$NOME_ARQ" | cut -d" " -f2)

##2 - convert to utf-8
iconv -f "$CODIFICACAO" -t utf-8 "$NOME_ARQ" -o temp01.txt

done
```

Have tried several ways for the ##1, but always get the following error:

```
sc-sini2csv: line 5: sintax error near `token' unexpected `CODIFICACAO=$(file --mime-encoding "$NOME_ARQ" | cut -d" " -f2)'
sc-sini2csv: line 5: `CODIFICACAO=$(file --mime-encoding "$NOME_ARQ" | cut -d" " -f2)'
```

We see from the error, that the problem occur when assigning the variable $CODIFICACAO

As far as I've looked around there are 2 ways of assigning the STDOUT to a variable:

1- using backtick:

```
CODIFICACAO=`file --mime-encoding "$NOME_ARQ" | cut -d" " -f2`
```

or

2- using $():

```
CODIFICACAO=$(file --mime-encoding "$NOME_ARQ" | cut -d" " -f2)
```

Both of them will give the same error.

As I wrote, it seems silly, but I'm stucked on this error..... any hel will be much appreciated !!!

PS: using $() or backticks directly from terminal (outside a bash script) will work.... but i need it into a shell script.

In time: I'm using ubuntu with bash shell

Thanks in advance !!!
Silvio

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a semi-colon:

```
for NOME_ARQ in *.txt; do
```

Comment: .... I was so blind searching for a problem at the variable assignment that I forgot the for/do sintax..... Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1):

`do` should be on a new line:

```
for NOME_ARQ in *.txt
  do
```

Comment: .... I was so blind searching for a problem at the variable assignment that I forgot the for/do sintax..... Thank you !!!! Lost a lot of time there...... Also the error message did not helped...